# single-spa root application as a react application

Tags: reactjs, single-spa-react

I have created a root project using the command

`create-single-spa`

Now I actually have a wrapper project which works on module federation internal to my company, which accepts only react applications to be imported.
So inside this wrapper project which works on MF, I want to import my single spa root project so that I can actually plug-in my whole single-spa project into the same.The root project has 2 main files, index.ejs & abc-root-config.js . But I needed a react project to be imported inside my wrapper project. One idea I could think of was to convert root-app into a react project but still that doesn't work as expected because still the main files are ejs & root-config not a react fileAny ideas on how this should be done?